# Salesforce Problem with Data Loader, Java version and installing the software

Tags: java, salesforce, dataloader

i'v installed the latest version of Zulu Jdk and DataLoader to get Data Loader on my computer, but after extracting the files from the compressed file of the DataLoader, and trying to run the install.bat file, I get this message in a command prompt that pops up and disappears right away:
"Data Loader requires Java JRE 17 or later. Checking if it is installed..."

when verifying the version of java on my computer I see that I do have a late enough version of java - as you can see in this image:[image: the existing v of java I have installed]

so what can the problem be?

does anyone know?

I looked around numerous times to find an answer or at least a direction to be able to progress with the problem using different wordings, but did not find any solution, or anyone posting a question that mentions having a similar issue.

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.

Answer (score 1):

After not succeeding with the desired version,
I downloaded a previous version of DataLoader: "dataloader_win_v57.0.1",
and it worked just fine.

BTW if it helps anybody - I had to add to Path in the environment variables the 'C:\Windows\System32' directory so the installation should work, it wouldn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the path of the installed Zulu to JAVA_HOME and it works

Comment: I've already tried that, and it did not help.